# YouTube video in video_player package

Tags: flutter, youtube, video-player

i started use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player. But me need use this package for showing video from YouTube videos, how can i do this, cuz default ulr from YouTube not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin for playing YouTube videos. It doesn't support that. You can play videos from network but it should be video (ends with a valid extension). YouTube videos are different.

You need to use something like [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter), or [youtube_explode_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart). You can search other plugins on pub for this as well.

Comment: Okay thank you. These packages (what you sent) can they play videos from different url or just youtube?

Comment: You're welcome. Those can only play youtube videos.

Comment: I highly DO NOT recommend you use youtube_player_flutter. It does not compatible with old android versions (below 11) to give you fresh view, I do highly recommend you this one: [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe)